# Are the bigger buttons in RWD sites really a good experience to mouse users?

Tags: css, responsive-design

*Not sure if this is the right place to ask this question, so please feel free to close it and suggest a better place to ask this questions.*

Most of the RWD sites today increase the size of buttons when the window width decreases. This makes a lot of sense because when the window size is small enough, RWD sites will show the mobile web experience, which requires a bigger touch target.

However, as a desktop browser user on a non-touch device, when I choose to use a smaller window size, what are touch-optimized (bigger buttons) buying me? Probably not much, considering the screen real estate is now occupied more by the elements that are "unnecessarily" big?

Same applies to the other direction of the problem. Are the "small" buttons on a touch device with wide window size a good experience?

<s>An alternate solution is to do browser detection on the server side to best guess if it is a touch device (e.g. iphone vs. desktop) and deliver a touch optimized CSS to the client.</s>

So, as a developer, what are the trade-offs for which approach to take? What is the philosophy/principle to follow?

Comment: You might want to DuckDuckGo "RESS".

Comment: Device detection is fraught with issues and certainly a worse solution than feature detection. Do a bit of research and see for yourself: https://www.google.com.au/#q=why+is+device+detection+bad. Detecting touch support is **trivial**; if you're trying to guess whether a device supports touch, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: checkout css media queries

Comment: @ChristianVarga I know device detection on the client side is not the best, but I'm talking abt server side detection. The goal is not to deliver touch-opt CSS to client. So, is there a trivial way to detect touch support on the server side? Or, do you have suggestions o how to achieve the same goal using another approach?

Comment: @Horatio I know media queries, but which specific one that can help this situation?

Comment: Yeah buzzword, extra hipster points for xeroxifying a non-mainstream company in place of G

Comment: @louis.luo If client side device detection is bad, then how would server side device detection be any better? I don't think you understand how feature detection works. Tools like Modernizr apply a class to the html element (eg, `.no-touch` or `.touch`) depending on what the device supports. You can use those classes to apply different CSS depending on the feature. If you wanted bigger text on a touch device, you could use `.touch .my-element { font-size: 2em }`. Devices that don't support touch won't match that selector, so it won't get applied. There's no need to do anything on the server.

Comment: And if that still doesn't make sense, here's a jsFiddle demonstrating this behaviour: https://jsfiddle.net/suL1enop/. Load it up on touch & non-touch devices and see the difference. You could use code like that to serve bigger buttons on touch-enabled devices, thus solving the problem in your question without any hacky server-side device detection.

Comment: @ChristianVarga What you said makes total sense and thx very much for the example. By no means I'm saying server detection is better (thus, I originally said "best guess"). The reason why I mentioned guessing was to avoid delivering additional css when unnecessary. I get that the impact for the additional bytes may well be negligible in most cases.

Comment: @ChristianVarga Going back to the original Q, I think u're saying showing big buttons for mouse users on small browser window size is not the best. You're suggesting we should not simply rely on window size to decide to show bigger touch target, instead, we should do detect if touch is supported on client. This makes sense. The only thing is that it will still deliver unused css because touch-opt css will be delivered, but not used. Though, the unused css should usually have 0 impact on perf. Please let me know if I understood it wrong. Thx. :)

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be through feature detection in the browser. Since there is not a standard way of detecting touch through CSS. I would just do this JavaScript:

```
if ('ontouchstart' in document) {
    // Bring in the necessary CSS optimized for touch
}
```